# Alter SQL table - allow NULL column value

Tags: mysql, sql, alter

Initially, the table "MyTable" has been defined in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyTable` (
  `Col1` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Col2` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Col3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
);
```

How to update it in such a way that the column "Col 3" would be allowed to be NULL?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following MySQL statement should modify your column to accept NULLs.

```
ALTER TABLE `MyTable`
ALTER COLUMN `Col3` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: Yeah,but when I edit the column Col 3 (Date), it get the value '0000-00-00' automatically. But I want it to be equal to NULL.

Comment: UPDATE TABLE MyTable SET Col3 = null WHERE Col3='0000-00-00'

Comment: Wait... isn't Col3 a varchar(20), not Date ?

Comment: Empty strings and NULL values are different things, in MySQL query browser it is a little bit confusing this.

Comment: I do it without "DEFAULT" keyword.is it necessary?

Comment: I don't think the provided code actually works, according to the [spec](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html):  
`ALTER [COLUMN] col_name {SET DEFAULT literal | DROP DEFAULT}`  

it should be ``ALTER TABLE `MyTable`  
ALTER COLUMN `Col3` SET DEFAULT NULL``, shouldn't it?

Comment: I have a column name 'Null' which has values 'No'...how to alter it as 'Yes'

Answer (score 29):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable MODIFY Col3 varchar(20) NULL;
```

Comment: When I edit the column (try to make it empty) in MySQL Query Browser, the following error message occurs: Data truncated for column 'Col 3' at row 1. It happens after your updates.

Comment: if i try ALTER TABLE spen_recipe MODIFY Null varchar(20) NULL; i get err

Comment: @SachinS: What's that first `Null` doing there?

Comment: have jus set the description as default to unsigned NOT NULL

Comment: @SachinS: It should be `ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> <data_type> NULL;`.

Comment: @David: did you intend that to be a comment on my answer?  Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @eggyal: MODIFY COLUMN works on MySQL and Oracle prior to 10G version.

Answer (score 0):

This works in PSQL, not sure if it also works in normal SQL.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ALTER COLUMN columnname DROP NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE school MODIFY COLUMN school_van varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL;
```

"ALTER" keyword didn't work but "MODIFY" worked fine in MySQL 8.0.26

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32398208)