# I need allows null value in database update

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

When I update with a null value I have this error:

The value for column `velocidad_micro` in table `Partes` is `DBNull`

This is my code:

```
EnumerableRowCollection<Inventario_MediosDataSet.MedioRow> row_medio = table_medio.GetData().Where(c => c.ns_medio == numero_serie);
    Inventario_MediosDataSetTableAdapters.MedioTableAdapter table_medio = new Inventario_MediosDataSetTableAdapters.MedioTableAdapter();
    table_medio.Update(fecha_alta, null, activo, t, marca, num_serie, row_medio.First().fecha_alta, row_medio.First().fecha_baja, row_medio.First().activo, row_medio.First().id_tipo, row_medio.First().id_marca);
```

Comment: What is the definition of the table `partes`?

Comment: You can instruct the DB to allow nulls; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597982/alter-sql-table-allow-null-column-value

Comment: Sorry the table is Medio

Comment: I have defined that allow null in field fecha_baja in the table Medio in SqlServer but either way when I try to upgrade from the tableadapter table_medio gives me the exception. What can I do?